# Monitor Screens vs Scroll Bar variations with Page Layout Shift

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, flexbox

I have a use case where I have to enable or disable scrolling based on some condition.
I am developing this for both Mobile and Desktop environment.

Lets say condition is onClick of some component -

1. OnClick : I am setting -

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow-y: overlay;

   &.prevent-scroll {
     overflow: hidden;
   }
 }
}
```

In this scenario, I am able to disable scroll by onClick is active when using Mac - Chrome and there is no Page Layout Shift.
When I connect a Monitor (ThinkVision - not sure of specs) and do the same there is a Page Layout Shift.
This is due to scroll bar present on the right in the monitor and using a part of space on the screen. But while only viewing on Mac, the scroll bar does not have a dedicated space.

So I did some research and updated my css code to -

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    &.prevent-scroll {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  
}
```

This solved the problem on both screens but on Mobile, I could see that the screen was still scrollable at a very low pace.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is vague: "On mobile... ...was still scrollable at a very low pace"; can you be more specific? What do you mean by this? What is the mobile device? An iPhone? If so, then perhaps you are conflating scrolling with the "elastic" or "bounce" effects iOS introduces which occurs alongside scrolling. These effects can be inhibited too, with additional CSS rules... but I have no idea if this is what you're talking about.